# Volume issue with pulseaudio on Debian 11

Tags: linux, audio, debian, pulse-audio

I recently installed new Debian 11 on my desk, my audio devices are managed by pulseaudio and pavucontrol. I mainly use DragonFly red DAC to listen music or something else on Chromium. Everything is fine until there. However, I have one annoying problem with this config. I really think that is link with my DAC because I don't occur this problem with my other devices (like Logitech PRO X).

I set my DragonFly red DAC to 50% of volume through pavucontrol but after each reboot of my computer, the volume bar still appears at 50% BUT the sound seems to be at 100% of volume (RIP my ears). I have to go in pavucontrol and change manually 1 or 2 percents of the bar to get the expected volume (in this case 50%)

I searched all the day a solution, I only find something like "add line flat-volumes = no inside of this file -> /etc/pulse/daemon.conf". It does not change anything at all ! The problem is still here. By the way this line is already set in this file by default.

I also find this link which is the same problem than me : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/issues/1002
But it was for pipewire and not pulseaudio...

Does anyone have a solution to this ? Thanks !

Comment: I get this error message in syslog when I start pavucontrol :
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
device [8086:a32c] error status/mask=00001000/00002000

Answer (score 0):

I just find something that seems to work for me.

e.g https://askubuntu.com/questions/15069/how-do-i-change-the-way-ubuntu-adjusts-my-volume-mixer-levels

EDIT

If someone has the same issue, try to replace this line : **load-module module-udev-detect** by this line : **load-module module-udev-detect ignore_dB=1** inside of /etc/pulse/default.pa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).